# How do I enable VirtualBox shared clipboard/drag-and-drop?

Tags: virtualbox

Running Windows 8 guest in Xubuntu 13.10 host. VirtualBox 4.2.16.

I set bidirectional clipboard and drag-and-drop in the menu.

But... neither of these works. If I drag a file from Ubuntu to Windows, the cursor goes correctly from Ubuntu to Windows, but dropping the file does nothing. If I drag from Windows, the cursor does not leave the guest window.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag and drop currently (v4.3.8) works with Linux guests only, and only in the host->guest direction. Use a shared folder as an intermediate location.

From this [Link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=60466).